# What does the method `method` do in `&Unit.method(:new)`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to the Rails and trying to figure out the code that im given. What does the method `method` do in  `&Unit.method(:new)` ? And what is the meaning of `&`? There's not method `method` in Unit model and wondering why it can be there. And lastly, I guess the symbol `:new` creates a new object of `Unit` ?

```
class Unit
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :number 
end


class Product
  include ActiveModel::Model
  .........
  .........
  def units=(values)
    @units = values.map(&Unit.method(:new))
  end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide more context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method `method` is defined in the class `Object` and thus available on all objects. It takes as its argument the name of a method and returns a `Method` object that can be used to reflect on or call the given method.

So `Unit.method(:new)` gives you a `Method` object that represents the method `Unit.new`.

Now the unary `&` operator takes a `Proc` object or something that can be converted to a `Proc` using `to_proc` (which `Method` objects can) and then converts it to block.

So `&Unit.method(:new)` creates a block that calls the `Unit.new` method, making `values.map(&Unit.method(:new))` equivalent to:

```
values.map do |value|
  Unit.new(value)
end
```